# Access VBA copyobject error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I am trying to write a simple VBA in access that copies one table into another access Database and renames it.

Here is my code:

```
sub copy_table ()

    dim destDB as string
    destDB = "Y:\GDA_files\MI1.mdb"

    docmd.copyobject destDB, "Progress tracking 1", acTable= acDefault, "Progress tracking " & date

end sub
```

However I receive message

> Run time error '2501':
>
> The CopyObject action was cancelled

I have no idea why this error occurs. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> ```vb
> DoCmd.CopyObject(DestinationDatabase, NewName, SourceObjectType, SourceObjectName)
> ```

You probably have mixed up the `NewName` and `SourceObjectName` parameters.

And `acTable= acDefault` makes no sense.

Try:

```vb
' this will sort table names chronologically
strNewName = "Progress tracking " & Format(Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd")

DoCmd.CopyObject destDB, strNewName, acTable, "Progress tracking 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried put table name between back quotes?

> Table names can contain any valid characters (for example, spaces). If
>   table names contain any characters except letters, numbers, and
>   underscores, the name must be delimited by enclosing it in back quotes
>   (`).

in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/table-name-limitations